# How we can edit data by id in codeigniter using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, foreach

controller:edit_details

---

```
 public function index()
 {
      $this->load->model('edit_details_model'


    $this->load->view('edit_details_view',$data);
 }

public function editdetails($id)
{

    $this->load->model('edit_details_model');
    $data['value']=$this->edit_details_model->edit_data($id);
    $this->load->view('edit_details_view',$data);   
}

public function update_details()
{
    $this->edit_details_model->update_data();
    $this->getall();
}
    }
```

---

model: edit_details_model

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('form');
}

public function edit_data($id)
{
    $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('employee');
    $query=$collection->findOne( array( '_id' => ($id)) );
    return $query;
}
```

}

view:edit_details_view

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
 //collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('employee');
//  $cursor=$collection->findOne( array( '_id' => new MongoId($id)) );

if (is_array($value) || is_object($value))
{
foreach($value as $document)
{
  $id=$document["_id"];

 $name=$document['name'];

 $email=$document['email'];
 $phone=$document['phone'];
 
 
 
}

}
?>
<form role="form" name="frm1" method="post" ><?php echo form_open('edit_details/update_details')?>

 NAME<input type="text" name="ntxt" value="<?php echo $name;?>" /><br />
    EMAIL<input type="etxt" name="etxt"  value="<?php echo $email?>"/><br />
    PHONE<input type="ptxt" name="ptxt"  value="<?php echo $phone?>"/><br />
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    
</form>

</body>
```

it shows undefined name,email and phone in the from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach($value as $document)
{
   $id=$document->_id;

   $name=$document->name;

   $email=$document->email;
   $phone=$document->phone; 
}
```

Comment: still it is not working, it says undefined variable $name,$email and $phone in form value

Comment: take  $id ="";  $name =""; $email =""; $phone  =""; before  foreach()  @HemChudgar

Comment: thanks! got the solution..but it there is some in the edit_data code in model..it doesnt retrieve any data from database

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); print your query @HemChudgar

Comment: there is some error with edit query..it fetches the id but it doesnt work on view form..I think the problem is in foreach loop..it shows error related to that..both edit and update is not working @mayank Vadiya

Comment: In the edit query if I use $query=$collection->findOne( array( "_id" =>new MongoId($id))); instead of  $query=$collection->findOne( array( '_id' => ($id)) );  it shows error "Cannot use object of type MongoId as array" on  $name=$document['name'];